# const var does not keep its value

Tags: html, angular, constants

```
if (dashboardConfiguration.widgets.filter(w=>{
        return w.widgets.filter((wid)=>{
                if(wid.extension === WidgetExtension.Score){
                     if(this.IsInvalidValidScoreWidget(wid)){
                        wid.isValid = false;
                       const Temp=0;
                        return wid;
                         }
                     else{
                       const Temp=1;
                     }
                } 
                
        });
    }).length >0){
        results.set('widget', false);
        results.set('valid', false);
    }

    return results;
   
}
```

and my temp does not work so my `*ngIf` does not work although Temp is const. Actually I need to show the mat-icon when Temp is 0. Would you please  help? here is my html and I am filling out the Temp in a service but by its value i am trying to control my html elemnt.

```
<li *ngIf="licensePackage && licensePackage.id===100"  >
        <a routerLink="kpi-view" routerLinkActive="active">  
            <div class="tw-w-3 tw-float-right -tw-mt-3"  *ngIf="Temp===0">
                <mat-icon svgIcon="alerts_outlined" class="tw-max-w-3" aria-hidden="true"></mat-icon>
            </div>
            {{'menu_Summary_View' | translate}}
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: *"my temp does not work"* - The code shown declares two variables called `Temp`, never does anything with them, and immediately discards them.  Neither of these variables is ever used, or even observed.  Can you clarify what you mean by "does not work", to include specific debugging observations and specific expectations?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but it is const so i am thinking that when ever it become 0, it must keep this value then i will be able to use Temp in *ngIf in my html file for controling to show my mat-icon.

Comment: Actually I am filling out the "Temp"  in a service but by its value i am trying to control my html element.

Comment: You should put more effort into your question and provide proper code formatting with minimal code examples that allow us to replicate the issue by clicking "run".

Answer (score 0):

For temp to work correctly, you must declare it in your class instead of your function like this:

```
export class myClass {

   public temp : Number;
   ...

}
```

then in the `if`: `this.temp = 0`

Comment: But I am filling outthe Temp in a service not in this component BUT i need to use it for controlling the html page for this component.

Answer (score 0):

you can have two methods in service. one for your normal data returns and another one for Temp value.
or

you can add the value of Temp in the results (i.e. results.set('Temp', Temp);)